Find length of shortest substr that can be removed from a string resulting in a uniqueness
Just failed a coding challenge for an interview and now im scratching my head. How can one accomplish this task?
Given a string s of length n, the task is to find the length of the shortest substring, which, upon deletion, makes the resultant string consist only of distinct characters.
Here is my total failure of code that I ran out of time on... Was I at least going down the right path?
from collections import Counter
def findShortestSubstring(s):
char_freq = Counter(s)
targets = {char for char, idx in char_freq.items() if idx > 1}

if not targets:
return 0

min_len = float('inf')
left = 0
window_counts = Counter()

for right, char in enumerate(s):
if char in targets:
window_counts[char] += 1

while all(window_counts[char] > 0 for char in targets):
min_len = min(min_len, right - left + 1)

if s[left] in targets:
window_counts[s[left]] -= 1
left += 1

return min_len
optimized_test_results = {
"aabbcc": findShortestSubstring("aabbcc"),
"abcabc": findShortestSubstring("abcabc"),
"abcd": findShortestSubstring("abcd"),
"abba": findShortestSubstring("abba"),
"aaaabbbbcccc": findShortestSubstring("aaaabbbbcccc"),
"abcabcabc": findShortestSubstring("abcabcabc"),
"aabacbebebe": findShortestSubstring("aabacbebebe"),
"aabc": findShortestSubstring("aabc"),
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz": findShortestSubstring("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"),
"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa": findShortestSubstring("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa")
}



[ask] and [mre]

You can use a sliding window for O(n).

Is there any constrains related to e.g. complexity, memory usage, maximum string length, etc.

Just an advice which worked for me, unrelated to the question: always start from a brute-force solution. Determine its complexity; maybe it's already good enough? If not, find obvious routes for optimization. Then find the less obvious ones. If you run out of time during this process, at least you will have a partial answer.

Here's an O(n) solution.  It finds the longest cyclic substring with unique chars that touches an end of the string, and then returns the length of the remainder as the substring to remove:
def findShortestSubstring(s):
    slen = len(s)
    if slen < 2:
        return 0
    # find longest cyclic sequence of unique chars that touches an end
    chars = set()
    maxlen = 1
    curlen=0
    for startPos in range(len(s)):
        while s[(startPos + curlen) % slen] not in chars:
            chars.add(s[(startPos + curlen) % slen])
            curlen += 1
        if startPos == 0 or startPos + curlen >= slen:
            maxlen = max(curlen, maxlen)
        chars.remove(s[startPos])
        curlen -= 1
    
    # the substring to remove is the part not in that longest string
    return slen - maxlen

